# PHP. How to add variable inside foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Code:

```
@foreach($shoppinglists->getShopPrices() as $sh)
            <tr>
                @foreach($shoppinglists->getShopNames() as $ss)
                    <td>{{$sh->$ss->shop_name}}</td>
                    @endforeach
            </tr>
```

`$ss->shop_name` returns property of `$sh`, but with this code I get error:

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

I expect the result of the code to be:

```
<td>{{$sh->shop1}}</td>
<td>{{$sh->shop2}}</td>
<td>{{$sh->shop3}}</td>
...
```

Comment: What is with all the `@`s... some kind of template engine? Which one?

Comment: This is Laravel syntax

Comment: The main problem is with `$sh->$ss` which isn't going to work as `$ss` is an object of type `stdClass`. Are you not just wanting `$ss->shop_name`?

Comment: you might possibly (?) be able to do `$sh->{$ss}` ?

Comment: @JonStirling I need to put data from `$ss->shop_name` to `$sh` property. For example `$ss->shop_name` will output `shop1` and `$sh->shop1` will output `500 dollars`. I need information about price for respective shop.

Comment: @RamRaider Didn't understand it. Could you please give an example. Thank you!

Comment: I think that @RamRaider meant that you could do that like: 
{{ $sh->{$ss->shop_name} }}